# OS X: Terminal output of javac is garbled

Tags: java, macos, localization, utf-8, javac

I've got my computer set up in Japanese (hey, it's good language practice), and everything is all fine and dandy... except `javac`.  It displays localized error messages out to the console, but they're in Shift-JIS, not UTF8:

```
$ javac this-file-doesnt-exist.java
javac: ?t?@?C??????????܂???: this-file-doesnt-exist.java
?g????: javac <options> <source files>
?g?p?\?ȃI?v?V?????̃??X?g?ɂ??ẮA-help ???g?p???܂
```

If I pipe the output through `nkf -w`, it's readable, but that's not really much of a solution:

```
$ javac this-file-doesnt-exist.java 2>&1 | nkf -w
javac: ファイルが見つかりません: this-file-doesnt-exist.java
使い方: javac <options> <source files>
使用可能なオプションのリストについては、-help を使用します
```

*Everything* else works fine (with UTF8) from the command-line; I can type filenames in Japanese, tab-completion works fine, vi can edit UTF-8 files, etc.  Although `java` itself spits out all its messages in English (which is fine).

Here's the relevant bits of my environment:

```
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LANG=ja_JP.UTF-8
```

From what it looks like, `javac` isn't picking up the encoding properly, and `java` isn't picking up the language at all.  I've tried `-Dfile.encoding=utf8` as well, but that does nada, and documentation on the localization of the JVM toolchain is pretty nonexistent, at least from Google.

Addendum:

Macports OpenJDK6 has better behavior:

```
$ /opt/local//share/java/openjdk6_bootstrap/bin/javac this-file-doesnt-exist.java 
javac: file not found: this-file-doesnt-exist.java
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Comment: @Don Werve: warau :)  +1   Konitchiwa Don, genki? You wrote *I've got my (OS X) computer set up in Japanese* but you really don't right? You've got a particular user account set up in Japanese because from that standpoint OS X is quite different than Windows (where in Windows, if you want a Japanese Windows, you need the Japanese install CD, at least that's how it used to be [been there, have installed Windows 98 [!!!] in Japanese). In OS X you can change the OS' language at will AFAIK.  Not that it helps with your interesting question (at least for an OS X / Java / Japanese nerd like me ;)

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: OS X doesn't have different localized versions for different markets, so when you go to install a fresh OS, you can choose a default from any of the available languages.  So yep, my computer's default language is indeed Japanese.

Comment: it's better than that on OS X as far as I know, which kinda was the point of my comment: even after an install, you can *switch at any time* your language (If I'm not mistaken).  If you want to try chinese, you can... And then just switch back.  This doesn't mean a re-install.

Comment: @WizardOfOdds: Oh, totally; body my girlfriend and my business partner  occasionally use my laptop, and both of them prefer having it in English, which is a no-go on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a well-known glitch of javac on OS X in Japanese environment.
I had done a bit of Google searches myself, and I have found no fundamental cure. For now, the temporary solution I'm using is

```
javac -J-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```

which gives the error messages in Japanese encoded in UTF-8. Note that it's not `-D`, but `-J-D`. If you want the error messages in English, use

```
 LC_ALL=C javac -J-Dfile.encoding=utf8
```

You can always make them into an alias, if you'd like:

```
 alias javac="LC_ALL=C javac -J-Dfile.encoding=utf8"
```

Answer (score 0):

What character encodings have you enabled in Terminal? I'm guessing it does not allow the encoding that javac is using. Look under Preferences > Encodings.

Comment: I've got every encoding checked under 'Japanese', plus all of the UTF-* encodings.